# Save every object in scene as individual .blend files via python?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

There is an excellent example here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63000/37272 which saves all objects as .fbx files, but how do I get the script to save to .blend files instead?

EDIT: This line exports the selected objects to fbx: `bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=exportName, use_selection=True)`

How does the command look for saving the selected objects to a .blend file?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89624/how-to-create-a-blend-in-specific-directory-and-write-objects-on-it) and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89496/read-and-save-custom-data-outside-blend

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my add-on [Splode](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/splode). It can export individiual objects into individual blend files, and then link those blend files into the current file, replacing the existing objects. You should end up with the same scene, except that the objects are now linked from their respective blend file.

Comment: Thank you. Will check it out when I'm at computer again. I'm asking because I couldn't find a .blend way to do as it is done with the "export" functions: bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=exportName, use_selection=True)

Comment: I would love to try your add-on, however, I have no clue how to do it. I've installed "splode". It says: "location": "Je moeder" > "location": "Your mother"!? :-) In the userstories.md I find the line: "Artist presses "Splode to SVN" button." - but where is it? (I can tell you, that it isn't on "my mother"... ;-) )

Comment: There are buttons in the menu bar of the 3D View. As you've seen, it's all rather unpolished and experimental.