# How do I export objects from Blender separately?

Tags: objects, export, .fbx

I have a few objects in Blender (cube1, cube2, cube3, ....). The problem is that when I export them in .fbx format, Blender exports them as one object (so it is now  cube1, and there is no cube2, cube3 anymore). How do I export them separately, so I can later edit each of them ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export every object into separate files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62980/export-every-object-into-separate-files)

Answer (score 2):

Yes in when you have clicked what type it will export as (FBX etc.) in the bottom left of the screen tick "selection only".

Comment: Did you mean checkbox "Selected Objects" ? If so, it didn't work for me. Blender still exports objects as one mesh.

Comment: Really? Im unsure what is going on sorry about that

Comment: Yeah "selected objects" exports anything selected as one mesh. There is probably an addon to help with your problem though.